# How can i use case statement in where condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have this code. I want to use a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause, but it won't run:

```
SELECT 
    pdc_distribution,
    pdc_refund,pdc_type,
    pdc_amount 
FROM user_pdc_informations 
WHERE 
    (
        CASE WHEN pdc_type='D' 
            THEN (created_at BETWEEN 1583951400 AND 1584037799) 
            ELSE 1  
        END  
    ) 
    AND sport_id = 4 
    AND user_id = 7 
    AND match_id = 29743945
```

How can use case condition in this query?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, rather than just a query

Comment: Please explain what `1` supposed to do if, `pdc_type <> D`?

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'd take a strong bet it's supposed to mean `true`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `OR` instead:

```
SELECT 
    pdc_distribution,
    pdc_refund,pdc_type,
    pdc_amount 
FROM user_pdc_informations 
WHERE 
    (pdc_type <> 'D' OR created_at BETWEEN 1583951400 AND 1584037799)
    AND sport_id = 4 
    AND user_id = 7 
    AND match_id = 29743945
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean logic :

```
( (pdc_type = 'D' and created_at >= 1583951400  and created_at <= 1584037799) or
  (pdc_type <> 'D' and created_at = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` expressions produce ***values***, not code. In a `WHERE` clause, that means the result should be one side of a comparison with something else. In this situation, `CASE` is not needed at all.

```
SELECT 
    pdc_distribution,
    pdc_refund,pdc_type,
    pdc_amount 
FROM user_pdc_informations 
WHERE  (created_at BETWEEN 1583951400 AND 1584037799 OR pdc_type <> 'D')
    AND sport_id = 4 
    AND user_id = 7 
    AND match_id = 29743945
```

But to also show proper user of a CASE expression:

```
SELECT 
    pdc_distribution,
    pdc_refund,pdc_type,
    pdc_amount 
FROM user_pdc_informations 
WHERE 
   1 = CASE WHEN pdc_type = 'D' AND created_at BETWEEN 1583951400 AND 1584037799 THEN 1
           WHEN pdc_type = 'D' AND created_at NOT BETWEEN 1583951400 AND 1584037799 THEN 0
        ELSE 1 END
    AND sport_id = 4 
    AND user_id = 7 
    AND match_id = 29743945
```

One way to help write a valid case expression is to think about the data type for the result. Is it a varchar? Integer? Don't try to go for a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like that:

```
SELECT
    pdc_distribution
    ,pdc_refund
    ,pdc_type
    ,pdc_amount 
FROM 
    user_pdc_informations 
WHERE 
    created_at BETWEEN CASE WHEN pdc_type='D'  THEN 1583951400 ELSE 1 END AND CASE WHEN pdc_type='D'  THEN 1584037799 ELSE 1 END
    AND sport_id =4 
    AND user_id = 7 
    AND match_id=29743945
```